# Why do I receive Warning: Attempt to read property "nomGroupe" on bool in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, runtime-error, warnings

i have a problem in my code when i try to show the list of clients and their groups i have the Following error Warning: Attempt to read property "nomGroupe" on bool
[image]
here's my code
the view :

```
<table class="table table-bordered dataTable" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="dataTable_info" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row">
        <th class="sorting sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 73px;">ID</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 95px;">Nom</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Position: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 95px;">Prenom</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 31px;">Email</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 31px;">Adresse</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Office: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 58px;">Telephone</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Start date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 71px;">Groupe</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Salary: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 67px;">Crée par</th>
        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Age: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 31px;">Action</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php if (isset($rows) && $rows) : ?>

        <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?= $row->id_client ?></td>
                <td> <?= $row->nom ?></td>
                <td> <?= $row->prenom ?></td>
                <td> <?= $row->email ?></td>
                <td> <?= $row->adresse ?></td>
                <td> <?= $row->telephone ?></td>
                <td> <?= $row->nomGroupe ?></td>
                <td> <?= $row->creePar ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?= ROOT ?>/clients/update/<?= $row->id_groupe ?>">
                        <button class="btn-sm btn btn-info text-white"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                    </a>

                    <a href="<?= ROOT ?>/clients/delete/<?= $row->id_client ?>">
                        <button class="btn-sm btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </a>
                </td>

            </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <center>aucun client pour le moment</center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the Controller class :

```
<?php
class Clients extends Controller{
    private $client ;
    private $clients ;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client(); 
       //$this->clients= $this->getClients();
       }

    function index(){
      
        if(!Auth::logged_in()){
            $this->redirect("login");
        }
       $this->view("clients",['rows'=>$this->getClients()]);
    }

    public function getClients(){
        //get list of clients from database
        $this->clients= $this->client->findAll();
        //for each clients we will find his group and the user that added thus client to the db
        foreach($this->clients as $client){
            $groupe_tmp = new Groupe();
            $utilisateur_tmp = new Utilisateur();
            $val=$client->id_groupe;
            $groupe_tmp=$groupe_tmp->first('id_groupe',$val);
            $val=$client->id_utilisateur;
            $utilisateur_tmp=$utilisateur_tmp->first('id_utilisateur',$val);
            $client->nomGroupe=$groupe_tmp->nomGroupe;
            $client->creePar=$utilisateur_tmp->nom." ".$utilisateur_tmp->prenom;
        }
       
        return $this->clients;
    }

}
    

?>
```

the error :
[image]

Comment: `$client->nomGroupe=$groupe_tmp->nomGroupe;` You reassign `$groupe_tmp` at `$groupe_tmp=$groupe_tmp->first('id_groupe',$val);`, and the result is probably a false value.

Comment: And the reason for that most likely is a failing sql statement which you missed because of not having implemented error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The line of

```
$groupe_tmp=$groupe_tmp->first('id_groupe',$val);
```

returns a boolean value (presumably `false`) instead of returning a proper record, so, when your code reaches

```
$client->nomGroupe=$groupe_tmp->nomGroupe;
```

you get the error that you described. You can do something like:

```
$client->nomGroupe = is_bool($groupe_tmp) ? $groupe_tmp->nomGroupe : '';
```

Also, it is worth looking into your `first` `function` and see whether it's correct and why does it return a boolean. You might have a db issue as well.